# Apache Simple Rewrite Rules (XAMPP)

Tags: apache

My website document path: `C:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\mysite`

and I just want to rewirte for example, `http://localhost/scripts/mysite/index.php?page=home` to `http://localhost/scripts/mysite/home`

so Here is my `.htacess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Somehow if I type `http://localhost/scripts/mysite/home` in the address bar, browser says object not found.

I'm very new to rewirte rules, thanks for help!

Comment: Is your intention actually to take for example http://localhost/scripts/mysite/home and have it re-written to http://localhost/scripts/mysite/index.php?page=home so that PHP can process it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not this is correct way or not.

From

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

To

RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```